# AngularJS: Testing with FabricJS/Canvas

Tags: angularjs, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

How do you write tests for something like FabricJS in a directive and service?

Example app: http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/

I have been trying but I'm not making much progress without really bad hacks.
I want to integrate this service and directive into my https://github.com/clouddueling/angular-common repo so others can use this powerful library.

My scenario:

I'm trying to test my module that contains a service and directive.  Those link my app to FabricJS.  I'm having issues mocking the global `fabric` var that is created when you include the js file.  I'm assuming then I spy on the var containing the fabric canvas.

I just need to confirm that my service is interacting with fabric correctly. I'm having trouble mocking/stubbing fabric though.

To win the bounty:

- Example of a test I could use with Karma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult as you've not provided the code you want to test. However, for testability, I would firstly create a very small factory to return the global fabric object

```
app.factory('fabric', function($window) {
  return $window.fabric;
});
```

This factory can then be tested by injecting a mock $window, and checking that its fabric property is returned.

```
describe('Factory: fabric', function () {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  var fabric;
  var fakeFabric;

  beforeEach(function() {
    fakeFabric = {};
  });

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', {
      fabric: fakeFabric
    });    
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_fabric_) {
    fabric = _fabric_;
  }));

  it('should return $window.fabric', function () {
    expect(fabric).toBe(fakeFabric);
  });

});
```

An example service that then uses this factory is below.

```
app.service('MyFabricService', function(fabric) {

  this.newCanvas = function(element) {
    return new fabric.Canvas(element);
  }

  this.newRectangle = function(options) {
    return new fabric.Rect(options);
  }

  this.addToCanvas = function(canvas, obj) {
    return canvas.add(obj);
  }
});
```

You can then test these methods as below. The functions that return 'new' objects can be tested by creating a mock fabric object with a manually created spy that will be called as a constructor, and then using instanceof and toHaveBeenCalledWith to check how its been constructed:

```
// Create mock fabric object
beforeEach(function() {
  mockFabric = {
    Canvas: jasmine.createSpy()
  }
});

// Pass it to DI system
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('fabric', mockFabric);    
}));

// Fetch MyFabricService
beforeEach(inject(function (_MyFabricService_) {
  MyFabricService = _MyFabricService_;
}));

it('should return an instance of fabric.Canvas', function () {
  var newCanvas = MyFabricService.newCanvas();
  expect(newCanvas instanceof mockFabric.Canvas).toBe(true);
}); 

it('should pass the element to the constructor', function () {
  var element = {};
  var newCanvas = MyFabricService.newCanvas(element);
  expect(mockFabric.Canvas).toHaveBeenCalledWith(element);
});
```

The addToCanvas function can be tested by creating a mock canvas object with an 'add' spy.

```
var canvas;

// Create mock canvas object
beforeEach(function() {
  canvas = {
    add: jasmine.createSpy()
  }
});

// Fetch MyFabricService
beforeEach(inject(function (_MyFabricService_) {
  MyFabricService = _MyFabricService_;
}));

it('should call canvas.add(obj)', function () {
  var obj = {};
  MyFabricService.addToCanvas(canvas, obj);
  expect(canvas.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);
});
```

This can all be seen in action in this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CTlTmtTLYPwemZassYF0?p=preview

Comment: This needs to be a blog post!  The key I was missing was your first example with $window.  Would have never thought of that.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you write tests for an external dependency?

You start by assuming FabricJS just works. It's not your job to test it, and even if it were, you'd have to do byte stream comparison (that's what a canvas is, a stream of bytes interpreted as an image). Testing user input is a whole different thing. Look up Selenium.

Then you write tests for the code that produces the correct input for FabricJS.

Comment: He probably wants to write tests for an application-specific functionality, not visual representation. In Fabric we have both unit tests and functional tests. But for an app that uses Fabric, you could test the layer of functionality between Fabric and user actions (e.g. clicked that button? canvas should have 1 text object on it; not visually, but programmatically, through Fabric's object model — `canvas.item(0).type === 'text'`, etc.)

Comment: Yup, my terminology is not top-notch, but that's what I meant by "input for FabricJS", the API boundary.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of how you test a service that relies on a global var like `fabric`?  How do you mock that, what does it look like?  I just need to know that my service is working and calling FabricJS or whatever correctly.

Comment: Please keep discussion in the comments or modify your submission to answer the question.